# Convert Time.now into ActiveSupport::TimeZone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

My website has a functionality of using User system time unless they are logged in.

The problem comes when trying to test this functionality, as `Time.now.zone` gives me a string representation of the zone instead of an `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` object.

The one I get from `Time.now.zone` also can't be used to look up the timezone:

```
Time.now.zone
 => 'BST'
```

while I need:

```
 => #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00007ffe1afd9470 @name="Europe/London", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Europe/London>>
```

Comment: _"Time.now.zone gives me a string representation of the zone"_ – that's the expected behavior. From [`Time#zone`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Time.html#method-i-zone): _"Returns the **name** of the time zone [...]"_ (emphasis added). Same for [`ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone#zone`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-zone).

Comment: @Stefan I know that's the expected behaviour. But `Time.zone` or `TimeWithZone.zone` doesn't return the system time

Comment: `Time.zone` gives you the `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` instance. Isn't that what you are looking for? I'm a little confused. What is it that you want?

Comment: `Time.zone` does return `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`, but it returns it in *application time*, while `Time.now` will return *system time*. So for example, Time.zone will be in UTC, while Time.now will be in BST for me

Comment: You can set your application's time zone via `config.time_zone = "Europe/London"` in `config/application.rb`, see [Configuring Rails Components](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-rails-components)

Comment: But that's changing the Application time again, that's not what I want. This is being done in a system test and time is being grabbed on the client side by a Javascript library. I have no control over that. All I want is to also grab the system time in my test to correctly format the expected time, so I know what to look for with Capybara

Comment: You're asking how to get a `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` instance from `Time.now`. That implies that `Time.now` gives you the correct result. But `Time.now` – being a Ruby method – returns the server time, not the client time. However, you say that _"time is being grabbed on the client side"_. Can you post a more complete example? Maybe showing some client-side code (the time-fetching part), the request and the server side handling?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174247/discussion-between-maxim-fedotov-and-stefan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477037/stefan), my misunderstanding of `Time.now` has been cleared, it reporting server machine time, not user's, which of course makes all the sense. Thankfully, when it comes to tests, I can assume the client and server are the on the same machine, so its not a big problem.

I managed to also find a solution to my original problem. The method I was looking for was `getlocal`, which converts the `DateTime` object into system time(as mentioned above, that would be the server time, which is ok in tests). That made tests pass on both CircleCI and locally.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Time.zone` instead of `Time.now.zone`